# Windows Virtual PC losing network connection

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

On my Windows 7 host machine, I have a Virtual PC guest which runs Windows 2003 server R2.

After 10-15 minutes the guest loses the network connection. To fix this temporarily, I have to change the network to "none" in the VPC settings, then I change it back to the integrated VPC Realtek adapter. It works for 10-15 minutes before dropping again.

I have tried to reinstall the VPC network driver as Microsoft's KB described, but it only works for a few minutes and then it loses the connection again.